# Is there a way to find if an integer occurs in another integer?

Tags: javascript

For example if two integers A and B are given. Integer A occurs in Integer B at position P then the leftmost position should be returned.

For example,

- 53 occurs in 1953786 at position 2, so the function should return 2.
- 78 occurs in 1953786 at position 4 and 7.
- 57 does not occur in 153786.

Comment: Are you meant to treat these as integers, or can you just convert them to strings and use string operations like `indexOf`?

Comment: what does;"78 occurs in 1953786 at position 4 and 7" mean? I assume the 7 is a typo

Comment: Sorry for the formatting of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to a string and use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```js
function getIndex(num1, num2){
  return String(num1).indexOf(String(num2));
}

console.log(getIndex(1953786, 53))
```

Alternatively:

```js
function getIndex(num1, num2){
  return "".indexOf.call(num1, num2)
}

console.log(getIndex(1953786, 53))
```

Comment: indexOf is generic, so you can do `return "".indexOf.call(num1, num2);` to avoid the function call overhead, Global ref, and temp String object creation. Or even `let getIndex=Function.call.bind("".indexOf)`